# JS public static pattern

Tags: javascript

Um. What are we achieving through this JS pattern? (taken from here: [link](http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2011/11/few-javascript-patterns.html)) :

```
// public static
function Person() {
    Person.TOTAL++;
}
Person.TOTAL = 0;
```

Because it seems we can just do:

```
Person.TOTAL++;
```

Comment: Where did you find this?

Comment: @Jasper Kennis: there is a link in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a "public" property, in that it's gettable and settable outside the class, and it's "static" because there's a single instance of the property.

The counter is incremented in the constructor function, but can be modified externally. The pattern makes sense but this use of it is questionable.

Answer (score 1):

You count the number of Person object instances as every time `new Person()` is called, the static variable TOTAL will be incremented.

The function `Person` seems like a constructor function here.